# Proper Install Order For Visual Studio 2010 with SQL Server 2012 Business Intelligence

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, installation, virtual-machine, conflict

I have a Windows 7 64-bit (Ultimate) virtual machine and would like to install the following:

```
Visual Studio 2010 (Ultimate)
SQL Server 2012 Business Intelligence (with SSIS and SSRS)
```

but I am not sure if there is a correct order to install those items such that there will not be a conflict. I'm concerned because I know that VS2010 installs SQL Server 2008 express. I hope it will not over write my SQL Server installation with the 2008 version if I do SQL Server 2012 first.

Does VS2010 skip installing SQL Server 2008 if the newer version is already installed?

### Update:

I installed the files as indicated by Justin.
    The VS2010 installer detected that SQL Server 2012 was installed and installed 
    without any issues.
    When I ran VS2010 it told me I needed to install VS2010 SP1 because of the newer 
    SQL Server 2012 files that were already installed.
    I installed SP1 and ran VS2010 again and everything loaded and ran fine.
    I also loaded up SQL Server Management Studio and was still able to connect to 
    SQL Server 2012 without any problems as well.

Comment: I would first install sql server 2012, because he already have Visual studio BI, and then Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Thanks Justin for the reply. I will do that and revise my post to let everyone know how it went.

Comment: By the way, now is available Visual Studio 2012. It would be probably better compatibility. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the install of VS 2010, you have the option to skip the install of SQL Server.  If you use the defaults to install SQL Server Express, the instance name will be the default name of SQLEXPRESS.  If this instance name is already in use, the install will no-op and exit out.

If you do install Express as part of VS2010, you can always perform the upgrade (both edition and version) from SQL Server 2008 Express to SQL Server 2012 BI edition.

Comment: Actually, this answer is incorrect now with SP1.  I posted the blog article in another answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975936/proper-order-of-installation-vs-2012-express-and-sql-server-2012-express/17128836#17128836  In short, install VS2012 first before SQL2012, install service packs, and you'll be fine.