# Is SQL Server 2012 compatible with VS 2010?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2012

- I have VS 2010 Install in my PC and my company wants to use SQL Server 2012
- Is this SQL version is compatible with visual studio 2010?
- Currently i am using SQL Server 2008 so i want to upgrade it

please help me 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is compatible, you can continue upgrading it.

(i) Yes 
(ii) You can upgrade.

Read more on **[SQL Server Express 2012 & Visual Studio 2010](http://www.formatyourbrain.com/sql-server-express-2012-visual-studio-2010/)**

Comment: Thank you Sir for your response

Comment: mark if it helped

Answer (score 0):

Use don't have to worry until you have proper connection string and relavent management studio. The answer your question is "it will work".

Answer (score 0):

> I have VS 2010 Install in my PC and my company wants to use SQL Server
>   2012

Yes, you can.

> Is this SQL version is compatible with visual studio 2010?

Yes

> Currently i am using SQL Server 2008 so i want to upgrade it

Go ahead!

Answer (score 0):

Yes SQL Server 2012 version is compatible with VS 2010. You can upgrade it.

Refer the following link it will be easy for you

[Proper Install Order For Visual Studio 2010 with SQL Server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170074/proper-install-order-for-visual-studio-2010-with-sql-server-2012-business-intell)